# Как правильно собрать .jar проект Spring Boot+Maven?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Собрал в Eclipse не большой скелет (шаблон "config") для своих проектов, которые планирую в дальнейшем размещать на каком-нибудь облачном провайдере. В Eclipse всё работает хорошо. Собрал проект с помощью Maven (меню "run" => instal) и в результате получил файл проекта с названием ConfigSpringBoot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar в папке "target". Запускаю этот jar через командную строку Windows, а в итоге получаю ошибку "Whitelabel Error Page .... (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)." **Что я делаю не так?**

Проект в общем-то пустой, но содержит 5 классов и 4 страницы html (для проверки Thymeleaf и взаимодействия с БД). Кроме pom.xml и одной строчки в application.properties ("spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled: true"), никаких дополнительных конфигурационных файлов - нет. Так выглядит последняя версия pom.xml (пробовал разные варианты [Executable JAR with Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven)) но ничего не помогло:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ConfigSpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ConfigSpringBoot</name>
    <description>Config Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                            <mainClass>
                                BootMain
                            </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Я не уверен в правильности Prefix с указанием на папку "/WEB-INF/" в бине TemplateResolver, который находится в классе BootMain.

```
         @Bean
         public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
                SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
                templateResolver.setApplicationContext(context);
                templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
                templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
                templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                return templateResolver;
            }
```

[image: Структура папок проекта]
В pom.xml специально добавил зависимость spring-boot-devtools (true) в надежде увидеть ошибку в браузере и сделать printStackTrace. Однако, кроме сообщения  Server Error, status=500 ничего не увидел. При этом контроллер сделан таким образом, что при обращении по адресу localhost:8080 я должен получать ошибку 404 (страница не найдена). Это работает :) А при обращении по адресу http ://localhost:8080/people/index (стартовая страница проекта) я получаю status=500. Ещё раз хочу заметить, что через Eclipse всё работает. Такое недоразумение возникает толь после сборки проекта и запуска jar через cmd Windows.

Архитектура шаблона (проекта) выглядит следующим образом: [image: A simple Java architecture for web applications]

Comment: Будет хорошо, если вы упростите вопрос. Будет ещё лучше, если вы снабдите нас дополнительной информацией о "скелете", чтобы мы могли воспроизвести проблему, т.к. гадать на кофейной гуще - не очень эффективно :) Вам также стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем.

Comment: @0dminnimda Упрощаю вопрос :) Мне кажется, что исполняемый .jar не находит классы и файлы проекта. Папка "target" выглядит следующим образом: http://graphics-ru.3dn.ru/hlam/target.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых нужно упаковывать веб-проект не в .jar, а в .war Иначе не создаётся папка WEB-INF со всем содержимым, в том числе страницы .html и .JSP Для этого нужно поменять в pom.xml `<packaging>jar</packaging>` на `<packaging>war</packaging>` Ответ на этот вопрос есть на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670491/web-inf-not-included-in-webapp-using-springboot-spring-mvc-and-maven). В данном случае, pom.xml должен выглядеть вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ConfigSpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ConfigSpringBoot</name>
    <description>Config Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Чтобы запустить проект через командную строку Windows, нужно правильно прописать пути к установленной jdk (на локальном компьютере) и к исполняемому файлу проекта. Структура папки "target" и окно командной строки (cmd Windows) должны выглядеть приблизительно вот так: [image: cmd windows]
Если всё сделано правильно, то все ошибки для разработчика (Exception printStackTrace) выводятся в консоль (cmd), а в браузере по адресу http://localhost:8080 отображается клиентская часть.